# Libgdx 1.5.4 requesting existing (already installed) Android API 20

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm currently trying to set up a libgdx project in 64-bit Arch Linux. However, I'm plagued with the error 'Please update your Android SDK, you need the Android API: 20' whenever I try to start a project.

However, according to the SDK manager I've already installed Android Build Tools 20, SDK Platform and Sources for API 20 as well (which is Android 4.4W.2, which is for Wear I believe? So I don't understand why this is the case at all). I also have 17, 19.01, 21.1.1, 21.1.2, 21, and 24.1.2 installed.

Is there something I'm missing here, or am I being told something is missing that I have installed? Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check and see if there's an update for your IDE.

Comment: @Dithanial I use android-studio but also have eclipse installed - both of which are updated.

I get that message before I touch the IDE though - it's when I click 'Generate' in the gdx-setup (project setup) window.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling API 20 and re-installing it?  I downloaded libgdx and it didn't have a problem, so I'm thinking there must be something wrong with your path.

Comment: @Dithanial Cheers. Hmm strange, I tried reinstalling it and the issue remains. The gdx-setup is pointing to /opt/android-sdk for the Android SDK which is where it's actually installed, however. What folder should I be looking for exactly?

Comment: I believe that would be it.  Just to verify though, that if you navigate to your sdk folder > build-tools, sdk folder > system-images, and sdk folder > platforms and make sure that they contain the version number it's looking for.  If so, just to check I'd open up Eclipse and find your specified sdk path and copy and paste it to your gdx-setup.

Comment: @Dithanial thanks for the heads up - turns out I was looking into the wrong path. All my SDKs installed from the SDK Manager were in fact in a folder in my home directory.

Comment: @Dithanial thanks for the heads up - turns out I was looking into the wrong path. All my SDKs installed from the SDK Manager were in fact in a folder in my home directory.

Should I add a reply to mark this as solved or just edit the original post seeing as it's not really a genuine issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to verify your path, open up Eclipse and find your specified sdk path and copy and paste it to your gdx-setup.